# Simple modal div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

I have tried almost all of the jQuery Modal plugins I can find on the net but they are all much to bulky for what I need.  I don't need all the fancy features, I want to be able to open a div and have the background of the page go transparent grey like the photo below and have my div be on top of it, that is all I need to do so I would like to write some jQuery to do this instead of using a bulky plugin.  Does anyone have any small code that can do this task?  Is the transparent background an image or just CSS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EDIT: This is obviously outdated. So please refer to Andrew Odri post below.**

I don't know how good you are in CSS and JavaScript, but your request shouldn't be that hard to do yourself.

```
body, html { margin:0; padding:0; }
#modalTabelGray
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:0.6;
    -moz-opacity:0.6;
    z-index:100;

    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#modalDiv
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:101;
}
```

I haven't tested the code, might not work, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: if this works, this is basicly what I needed help with is the css part

Comment: I haven't testet it, but as said, it shouldn't be that hard to make. The most important part, is that you don't nest the div in the div with opacity, because then the content will also become transparent. You can use a transparent PNG, instead if you like.

Comment: I think creating your own version could be a good idea. I will work for the first 2-3 tasks you want completed. But later on, you need it to be more complex. My experience tells me, that it will end up being more messy and end up being larger, than some of the other plugins out there. There are tons of them :-)

Comment: Actually I have only good experience with creating my own, they become just as lightweight as I want them, and I'm sure they don't conflict with other libraries I might use. But I do still agree with you, there are a lot of good plugins out on the internet, and things can get ugly when you create them yourself.

Comment: just add `top: 0px; left: 0px;` on the css and it should display as an overlay. 
tested on IE 10.

Answer (score 52):

This is what I use myself; it looks nice, the code is simple and easy to understand, and uses minimal CSS and jQuery.

Here is the code (And a fiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/cadkJ/125/):

**HTML**

```
<h1>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>

<p>Magna adipisicing eu, pig ex pariatur non biltong nisi consequat do exercitation. Biltong exercitation consequat aute. Excepteur velit ribeye, et salami pariatur sed consequat enim ham. Tenderloin consequat et, in pastrami aute meatloaf beef spare ribs tri-tip beef ribs sed ut jerky strip steak. Fugiat turkey shank frankfurter pork loin pastrami.</p>

<button id="modal-launcher">Launch Modal Window</button>

<div id="modal-background"></div>
<div id="modal-content">
    <button id="modal-close">Close Modal Window</button>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#modal-background {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: .50;
    -webkit-opacity: .5;
    -moz-opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: 1000;
}

#modal-content {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #222;
    display: none;
    height: 240px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -120px 0 0 -160px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    width: 320px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#modal-background.active, #modal-content.active {
    display: block;
}​
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $("#modal-launcher, #modal-background, #modal-close").click(function() {
        $("#modal-content, #modal-background").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

---

**Do you want to lock scrolling?**

Add the following CSS rule:

```
body.active { position: fixed; overflow: hidden; }
```

Replace the jQuery function with: (`body` added to line 3)

```
$(function(){
    $("#modal-launcher, #modal-background, #modal-close").click(function() {
        $("body, #modal-content, #modal-background").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

**Do you want to prevent click events on the background from closing the modal?**

Replace the jQuery function with: (`#modal-background` removed from line 2)

```
$(function(){
    $("#modal-launcher, #modal-close").click(function() {
        $("#modal-content, #modal-background").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: And just a heads up if you want to lock scrolling on the body (not part of the questions but perhaps helpful): Add the following CSS rule `body.active { position: fixed; overflow: hidden; }`, and change line 3 of the jQuery to `$("body, #modal-content, #modal-background").toggleClass("active");`

Comment: The look is nice and simple. But I question it being modal since clicking in the background closes it. Modal to me means only the close button should close it.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point @PeterNosko; to remove the background click behaviour, just change the second line of jQuery to `$("#modal-launcher, #modal-close").click(function() {`

Answer (score 6):

I would **NOT** recommend jQuery UI - it's huge and overcomplex for that simple task. Here are some other plugins:

- [ThickBox](http://bit.ly/ryj5W)
- [BlockUI](http://bit.ly/nanDw)
- [jqModal](http://bit.ly/YtiI1)
- [Facebox](http://bit.ly/8zLZn)

Comment: Yeah I will not use jqueryUI but I also want to stay away from other main ones liek you listed, they are "light weight" but not light weight enough for my needs

Comment: I will say the http://malsup.com/jquery/block/ I have not seen before and it is pretty nice!

Comment: I listed just some of the plugins that exists. Just google "jquery modal" and you will find lots of them. Some more complex than other :-)

Answer (score 3):

[SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) does precisely what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a simple modal using pure HTML and css,no need of javascript and   jquery,which will indirectly reduce time and work.

```
html-->
    <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

   <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
   <div>    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

        <h2>Modal Box</h2>

    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your    website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
   </div>
    </div>

      css-->

   .modalDialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
 }
 .modalDialog:target {
 opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
width: 400px;
position: relative;
margin: 10% auto;
padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #fff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
background: #606061;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -12px;
text-align: center;
top: -10px;
width: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
background: #00d9ff;
}
```

visit [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kumarmuthaliar/GG9Sa/1/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery UI which has a dialog plugin that supports modal .. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Alternatively you would create a div that spans the whole viewport in size, set its opacity to 50% (0.5) and also catch and stop all events to make it modal. Then display your div on top of it ..

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the jQuery UI Dialog for this.
http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0):

To name another plugin for this task is [nyromodal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/) which I find easy to use but still offers a lot of setting options if you should find yourself in the need for that (later)