# Customized popup window in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I need to open a popup, after checking a condition in javascript. I was trying to customize the popup window.

I used

```
function fun()
{
  if() {
     window.open('name.jsp','Popup','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=420,height=400,left=430,top=23');
  }
  else {
  }
}
```

But I needed a pop like what I have given below. 
Is it possible in javascript. 
image 1: what I am getting
image 2: what is needed.

[image: What is getting]       [image: What is needed]

Comment: Some browsers (most modern browsers) simply don't allow you to remove the title bar and menu and so forth.

Comment: What is the browser and version you are using?

Comment: Haha it's impossible. The image on the left is the best you'll **ever** get. And I wouldn't be surprised if more options were ignored in the future. I remember when the address bar would be hidden in popups that I'd get...that was awhile ago. You could look up modals!

Comment: @prageeth: I need all browser support.

Comment: You can do a "dialog" within the current page, i.e., a div that is on top of the main page. jQuery has some plugins to do that.

Comment: Have you considered a modal dialog within the current frame/window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for all the suggestions to use a modal instead of a popup winodw (which can't be styled how you want).

Modals are the more modern and user friendly way to go.  This post: [Simple modal div in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101359/simple-modal-div-in-jquery) has quite a few links in it that could get you started.

With a little css and an icon, you could get your modal to look exactly like your image 2.