# JavaScript Img pauses during prompt dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my project almost complete. There will be a codepen link with the project for debugging at the end of the post.

## What's Supposed to Happen?

The `img` holds the `id` property of `dragon`, as well as the `src` to force-load as the default image. It starts off with [this](http://www.thegaminghideout.com/img/index/dragonSlayer/stage1.png) `img` being (forced) pre-loaded when it's loaded. It should stay like that, then once the `decision1()` function is called, it should change it to [this](http://www.thegaminghideout.com/img/index/dragonSlayer/map.jpg) `img`. Once the `dragonBattle()` function is called, it should change the `img` to [this](http://www.thegaminghideout.com/img/index/dragonSlayer/dragon.gif) gif. If the player attacks (or calls the `hitDragon()` function), it should play [this animation](http://www.thegaminghideout.com/img/index/dragonSlayer/dragonFire.gif) once, then revert back to the `dragon.gif` image. Once the fight is over (or the function ends), it will revert back to the default image.

**KEEP IN MIND** that all of these functions/events are called by the users input via the `prompt("")` function. The whole time, there will be a `prompt()` dialog box open, which triggers the events.

## What Really Happens?

Everything explained in the **What's Supposed to Happen?** actually happens, **but** not what I am expecting/needing. Yes, it *does* happen in the background, but it seems that the animated gifs are not animated during the `prompt()`. Yes, it changes the `img` to the animation, but it's not animated, it's just paused really. Once you exit the `prompt()` box however, it starts (or really *resumes*) the animation playback.

## What's the problem?

The problem is the `img` doesn't play gif animations while the `prompt` dialog box is open.

## What's the question?

How can I have a gif (`img`) play/loop its animation while a `prompt` dialog box is open?

## Things to Note

- I have done this before, and it did work; the animation *did* play while the dialog box was open and the `img` was changed successfully. However, it seems that I have lost that code due to overwritten progress on code debugging.
- I only tested this on Chrome, and I am not sure if it's a Chrome thing or something in my code.
- I am very organized as you can tell.

## Code

**NOTE:** I cannot include a `codeSnippet` because of the functionality limitations. It doesn't load prompts, and therefore it cannot be used/tested/debugged correctly. Sorry for any inconvenience. Here is the CodePen with the project.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/FelixTheSpy/pen/gbWZzZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is paused when calling a `prompt`. Straight out of [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/user-prompts.html):

> 4. [Pause](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/webappapis.html#pause) while waiting for the user's response.

Pause includes the following:

> 2. If necessary, update the rendering or user interface of any Document or browsing context to reflect the current state.
> 3. Wait until the condition *goal* is met.

If you want the rest of the page to continue running, I recommend you create your own dialog and use a callback to process the response.

Comment: Would I be able to create my own dialog with JavaScript?

Comment: @TheGamingHideout Yes.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Will give a vote & accept  the answer, but I would do it via buttons, right?

Comment: @TheGamingHideout That's one way. I'd take an approach more like the answers here though: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2101359/1234256