# How to blur out website and not make the website "clickable"?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I created a if statement like this:

```
if (lehrling == null)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihren URL Key');", true);
    //Blur Website
    //Disable Website
}
```

is the statement is true, an alert is displayed. I also want to blur the website and not make it clickable... So you cant access any content of the website. When i click the alert message away, the website should close....

How can i Do this? are there any good js methods to do this? maybe jquery?

Comment: css filter blur - although this is an antipattern.

Comment: If there is a problem with a user not having access, then why load the page at all? Putting a 'blur' on things won't make it inaccessible

Comment: [Modal overlay in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101359/simple-modal-div-in-jquery)

Comment: if the access is not granted, how can i "not load" the website

Comment: Just redirect to an "access denied" page...

Comment: I think some of the answers are missing the point, a little. Yes; you asked for a solution to "blur" the page, but I believe the issue is a little deeper than just using CSS. I believe the point of SO is not *just* to answer a question directly, but to address other points that the OP might have missed (such as best practices, alternate solutions etc). As already stated, you're best off entirely redirecting the page from the back-end to an "Access Denied Page". From what I gather you're using ASP.NET (or similar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### NOTES ABOUT BLOCKING ACCESS TO USERS

If you want website to not be opened by some users, if there the access is denied for them, then bluring the website isn't a best practice as the user will be able to see the webpage source or remove the blur through developer tools. For that you should redirect the user to an access denied page, by the server side. In PHP, you can do it like

```
if($denied == true) { header("Location: /access-denied.html"); }
```

or

```
if($denied == true) { die('You cannot access this page because...'); }
```

or even show an alert box as you wanted and close the window, without showing the page, because, as I said, it is a bad practice to provide the source code to the user you don't want to access the page.

### However, bluring website (general example)

**After reading my notes, if you still want to do that, I have created, in the beginning, an example for a general case, as to be able to see the demo (your particularly code, modified, could be found at the bottom of the answer). *In the demo mode the window is not closing.***

```js
  $("#blur").click(function() {
    $('body').addClass('blur_site');
    alert("Good bye!");
    window.close();
  });
```

```css
.blur_site {
    filter: blur(1px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    -o-filter: blur(2px);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;    
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="blur">Blur</button>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vulputate dui eu massa volutpat laoreet. Suspendisse tincidunt mi sed dui egestas, quis euismod metus lacinia. Phasellus at dui odio. Etiam tempor egestas ligula ut hendrerit. Pellentesque arcu mi, mollis vel tincidunt ut, fermentum ac felis. Ut posuere libero ut erat vestibulum vulputate. Sed dolor turpis, imperdiet nec lorem sed, hendrerit vulputate nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ut mi at dolor rutrum pretium. Vivamus nec volutpat ipsum. Nam tincidunt sagittis pharetra. Fusce consectetur nibh sapien, ac dignissim libero elementum eu.
</div>
<p>
Nam id fermentum nisi. Fusce venenatis ligula non pretium commodo. Proin enim mi, mattis quis augue ut, volutpat sollicitudin ligula. Vivamus in congue purus, eget bibendum nisi. Cras dignissim sit amet magna et malesuada. Proin sem lacus, volutpat pretium maximus vitae, varius a enim. Etiam laoreet a lacus et accumsan. Cras porttitor porta velit ut faucibus.
</p>
<b>
Maecenas vulputate dui eu risus porttitor, pellentesque dictum orci mollis. Praesent ac arcu nisl. Sed purus sapien, ultricies at aliquam id, hendrerit dignissim mauris. Nullam et ante porta, finibus sapien vitae, sagittis felis. Pellentesque luctus urna sit amet lorem sodales, eu aliquam mi placerat. In quis viverra erat, non blandit risus. Etiam ornare nisi justo, a volutpat quam molestie sit amet. Nulla nec bibendum magna, non accumsan justo. Sed imperdiet quam at felis luctus, non tempor massa consectetur.

Suspendisse a justo id dui finibus volutpat id id lorem. Curabitur eu dui vitae nulla varius venenatis. Morbi neque erat, euismod ut facilisis eu, pellentesque vitae elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec purus ante, hendrerit eu maximus nec, ullamcorper ac nisl. Ut euismod eros ac lacus efficitur, vitae faucibus tellus lobortis. Integer viverra mauris ut tellus efficitur tincidunt sit amet vel dolor. Sed lacinia est vel ipsum pharetra, ut iaculis dui fermentum. Nam id nulla vitae ligula elementum euismod ac eget libero. Sed bibendum diam ut magna tempor, quis ultrices sapien placerat.

Pellentesque consectetur ex lorem, sed eleifend nunc tincidunt et. Ut at tellus feugiat orci accumsan ornare. Phasellus posuere arcu non urna consequat blandit. Praesent interdum sagittis lorem, sed congue elit. Duis vestibulum tempor lorem, at dapibus arcu finibus quis. Donec mauris mauris, egestas et ex vel, facilisis blandit nisl. Phasellus sit amet dictum tellus, vel dictum metus. Suspendisse placerat nisl mattis dolor consequat, at rhoncus magna pellentesque. Donec aliquet massa nec aliquet tempus. Cras eget venenatis nisl, eget posuere quam. Vestibulum maximus eu dui dignissim vestibulum. Pellentesque auctor purus et risus auctor, at accumsan erat pulvinar.
</b>
```

### Bluring website (your original code modified)

```
if (lehrling == null)
{
    $('body').addClass('blur_site');
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihren URL Key');", true);
    window.close();
}
```

And add this to your CSS:

```
.blur_site {
    filter: blur(1px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    -o-filter: blur(2px);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;    
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

**Note that this code is using JQuery.**

Comment: Personally, I would put your note about redirecting to an "Access Denied" page right at the top of your answer, as this is probably the most important point to make. If the user knows how to use the browser's F12 developer tools, then it is possible they could remove the `filter` and play with the JS a little :)

Comment: @GeoffJames You are right, it's pretty simple to view the content for most users on such a website. I edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A possibile direct solution.

```js
var dialog = $("div.Curtain");

function showDialog(content) {
  $("div#DialogContent", dialog).html(content);
  dialog.show();
}

$("div.Dialog").on("click", "a.Button", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var button = $(this);
  if (button.attr("id") == "CancelButton")
    dialog.hide();
  else
    alert("redirect somewhere or do other staff");
    
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.Curtain {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  display: none;
}

div.Dialog {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
  padding: 40px;
}

div.Dialog a.Button {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: cente;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  This is the content of the website.
  
  <a href="javascript:showDialog('dialog content');">show the dialog</a>
</div>

<div class="Curtain">
  <div class="Dialog">
    <!--A way can be to put the content of the dialog in a hidden div and showing it in front of a curtain when done.-->
    
    <div id="DialogContent"></div>
  
    <a class="Button" href="#" id="OkButton">Ok</a>
    <a class="Button" href="#" id="CancelButton">Cancel (redirect)</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a framework like JQuery or Bootstrap to use their Modal windows to achieve this.
In combination with Javascript you could also close the current browser window.

- Bootstrap Modal example: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp
- Jquery Modal Example: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message
- Javascript to close the browser: window.close();

That is all the information you need. Success!

Comment: can you help me get my asking right back. i got banned from asking cuz i didnt know how to ask and how to programm back then when i asked this. you would really help me with a upvote <3